# write stream info to video file

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, metadata

I have copied(downloaded) part of video file from s3 server in nodejs, now I am trying to write metadata to video file.

I have metadata of the original file got with following code

```
    ffprobeStatic = require('ffprobe-static');

ffprobe('./testfile.mp4', { path: ffprobeStatic.path }, function (err, info) {
    if (err) return 0;

    console.log(info);
});
```

I have tried with node-exiftool but could not make it work by the following code.

```
const exiftool = require('node-exiftool');
const exiftoolBin = require('dist-exiftool');
const ep = new exiftool.ExiftoolProcess(exiftoolBin);
ep
    .open()
    .then(() => ep.writeMetadata('./testfile2.mp4', meta_data, ['overwrite_original']))
    .then(console.log, console.error)
    .then(() => ep.close())
    .catch(console.error)
```

How can I write modified metadata (stream info) to my new file?

basically, the question is how can I collect video file (for example mp4), if I have stream info, all metadata and file bytes (chunks). 
Please correct me if anything wrong. thanks

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg will allow you write metadata from a file into an mp4.

There is documentation here: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata-1

Inserting metadata from a file uses a command like this, from the above link:

> ffmpeg -i INPUT -i FFMETADATAFILE -map_metadata 1 -codec copy OUTPUT

There are various ffmpeg wrappers for different frameworks - for example for nodejs, a common one is:

- https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg